# Zero MQ and Websockets

Tags: java, websocket, zeromq, wildfly

I currently have an architecture that is as follows:

1. Web UI using HTML 5 web sockets to connect to a web server
   (Wildfly).
2. On the web server I am both a subscriber and a publisher to two different ZMQ sockets.For each new user that connects to my web server I create a thread that continuously runs and listens for messages from upstream.
3. When I receive a new message I broadcast the update to all those users who are listening. The update then gets sent back to their web page using conventional web sockets.

This architecture seems simple enough but my web server will sometimes appear to hang without error or my upstream server will sometimes not receive the messages I publish over ZMQ. This only appears to happen when I try to publish a request back to my upstream server over ZMQ however.

With the above in mind, I would be really interested to know if anyone has created a system with similar technologies? If so could you explain your architecture?